# Arrangement of including script (Angular with jquery UI with Materializecss JS) not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, materialize

I am using materializecss to do my design together with Angular. At a certain part, I will need to use ([Angular-ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)) for me to be able to be able to sort my list which included jquery-ui. JQuery-UI needs to be included below JQuery and Angular-ui-sortable and it need's JQuery to be before AngularJS. By doing so, the sortable area works while materializecss' initialization of Tab after angular's content is loaded is not working. For the Tab to work, Jquery materialize css needs to be after angular's include. In this case the sortable wise will not work.

Tab works here with error (ui.sortable: jQuery should be included before AngularJS!):

```
<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> <---------------------

<script src="libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="libs/materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Sort works here with error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined):

```
<script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> <---------------------

<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="libs/materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Controller for Tab:

```
function HomeController() {    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    });
}
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Try loading jQuery after everything Angular.  Angular uses jqlite and loading it before material could reset all variables and cause an error.

Comment: @MatTaylor By doing so, I will have the error  (ui.sortable: jQuery should be included before AngularJS!)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined - what file does that come from in your second example?

Comment: @MatTaylor Most likely from my observation it should be materializejs and jquery js

Comment: That error appears during my controller tab

Comment: It should say what file is throwing the error though.

Comment: Might be worth throwing up a fiddle

Comment: it states angular.js:12520

Comment: I'll try to put it to fiddle, but not sure if i could replicate the probelm tehre as the project is quite large